# Can't run a serverless & bref basic example locally

Tags: macos, serverless, bref

I want to run a basic example of serverless & bref example.

What I did:

1. npm install -g serverless
2. composer require bref/bref
3. vendor/bin/bref init
4. serverless invoke local -f hello --docker

I getting this error:

```
Miroslavs-MacBook-Air:testing kosta90s$ serverless invoke local -f hello --docker
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
START RequestId: f815c369-8fa7-1671-cbbd-d623069bc9c2 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: f815c369-8fa7-1671-cbbd-d623069bc9c2
REPORT RequestId: f815c369-8fa7-1671-cbbd-d623069bc9c2  Init Duration: 15.78 ms Duration: 1.35 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 7 MB   

{"errorType":"exitError","errorMessage":"RequestId: f815c369-8fa7-1671-cbbd-d623069bc9c2 Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]"}
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Failed to run docker for provided image (exit code 1})
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:536:21
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              14.14.0
     Framework Version:         2.8.0
     Plugin Version:            4.1.1
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        3.2.7
```

serverless.yml

```
service: app

provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-east-1
    runtime: provided

plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref

functions:
    hello:
        handler: index.php
        description: ''
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-74}

# Exclude files from deployment
package:
    exclude:
        - 'tests/**'
```

I working on MacOs Catalina.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bref. But I think you added '--docker' by mistake. Can you try invoke function without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serverless invoke local` tries to use a Docker image named `lambci/lambda:${runtime}` where `runtime` is `phpX.Y` in your case.

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/6a81137406fd2a2283663af93596ba79d23e38ef/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js#L478

There is no such image as you can see here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/tags

As the comments said, try without `--docker`. If you need Docker, you can follow [the documentation](https://bref.sh/docs/local-development.html#http-applications) and use the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
    web:
        image: bref/fpm-dev-gateway
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
        volumes:
            - .:/var/task
        depends_on:
            - php
        environment:
            HANDLER: index.php
    php:
        image: bref/php-74-fpm-dev
        volumes:
            - .:/var/task:ro
```